# If x and y are positive real numbers such that x.[x] = 36 and y.[y] = 71,then x+y is equal to which number.[.]denotes the greatest integer function .

Tags: functions

My attempt:  Let (x+y)=c, where c is any number. then multiply the whole equation by [x][y], where [] denotes the floor function.

x[x][y] + y[y][x] = c[x][y].
36[y]+71[x]=c[x][y].

I don’t know how to proceed.

Comment: Just expand $x$ as $[x]+frac(x)$. You can then plug values to directly get $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

This came in NEST 2019

I solved it like 
Given X[X]=36
Now it's like [X]^2+[X]{X}=36
If I assume X=6 then 6^2=36 directly
So X+y=36/[X] +71/[y]=6+71/[y]

Now 71 is kind of 72 which is like 72/8=9 but 71/8 will be something like less than 9 but greater than 8 hence [71/8]=8

So 71/[y]=y put [y]=8 then y=71/8
Hence 36+71/8=119/8